# Linking Structured Data Snippets

Tags: structured-data, json-ld

All content is generated via CMS widgets. As a result the article structured data is generated via a separate widget to the authors. Is there some way I could link the two snippets together?

Example shortened for brevity:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",

      "author": "Reference below snippet"
    }
</script>


<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Person",
      // this is the person i want to be the author for the above article snippet

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the CMS you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have separate entities merge if you give them the same @id

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "author": {"@id": "#Author"}
    }
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Person",
      "@id": "#Author"
      // this is the person i want to be the author for the above article snippet
    }
</script>
```